# Converting a hex string representation of a widechar codepoint to a widechar in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, widechar

I am having trouble converting text within an edit box to a WideChar.  This is being used in code for printing emoji characters.

If I manually set the WideChar values like the following it works

```
Emoji[1] := WideChar($D83D);
Emoji[2] := WideChar($DC4D);
```

But I want to be able to set the hex codes via edit boxes as follows

```
StringToWideChar(edit1.text, @wc1, Length(edit1.text));
StringToWideChar(edit2.text, @wc2, Length(edit2.text));
Emoji[1] := wc1;
Emoji[2] := wc2;
```

wc1 and wc2 are defined as WideChar.  The edit boxes contain the same values as are hard coded above. That code results in a blank output, so something is wrong with the conversion.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Why not just type the actual Emoji into the `TEdit` and then use its `Text` as-is? [`StringToWideChar()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.StringToWideChar) doesn't do what you think it does. It is meant for converting a `String` to a `WideChar[]` buffer of equivalent length (ie, originally for converting `AnsiString` to `PWideChar`, now just a plain copy). It is not meant for paring a whole `String` into a single `WideChar`.

Comment: 10.4 so Andreas' code (with Remy's edit) works fine.  `Emoji[1]:=char(strtoint(edit1.text));`

Comment: Why use a separate `TEdit` for each UTF-16 codeunit? Why not use a single `TEdit` to enter a whole codepoint?  If you don't want the user to enter the actual Emoji symbol, then at least enter its codepoint value (ie, `'$1F44D'`) and then you can convert that to an integer with `StrToInt()` and then use [`TCharacter.ConvertFromUtf32()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharacter.ConvertFromUtf32) or [`TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.ConvertFromUtf32) to convert that to a proper `string`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Remy.  Using the whole codepoint and converting with ConvertFromUtf32 is much cleaner code and simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't interpret the string `'$D83D'` as text -- instead, you must parse it as an integer.

First, you need to obtain the text from the edit box. This is `Edit1.Text`. Then you need to convert this to an integer. For instance, you can use `StrToInt` or `TryStrToInt`. Then you simply need to reinterpret (cast) this integer as a `Char`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
var
  CodeUnit: Integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(Edit1.Text, CodeUnit) and InRange(CodeUnit, 0, $FFFF) then
    Label1.Caption := Char(CodeUnit)
  else
    Label1.Caption := '';
end;
```

Here, as a bonus, I also validate that the supposed codeunit is an actual 16-bit unsigned integer using `InRange` (I mean, the user could in theory type `123456789`). Delphi's `StrToInt` functions support hex using the dollar sign notation.

Comment: Technically, this is not actually working with *codepoints* at all, but rather with *codeunits* instead. That is an important distinction to make. U+1F44D () is a *codepoint*, `D83D DC4D` is a UTF-16 *codeunit* sequence (aka a *surrogate pair*). But yes, `0..$FFFF` is the correct range for a UTF-16 *codeunit*, which is what Delphi's `WideChar` represents. And you should be using a `Char()` type-cast, not `Chr()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Why do you prefer `Char` instead of `Chr`?

Comment: Well, for one thing, because the `Chr()` documentation says to. And second, because `Chr(X)` is not guaranteed to always return a `Char` with a value of `X` when `X` is `128..255`, whereas `Char(X)` is guaranteed to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Can you given an example of a Delphi 2009+ piece of code in which `Chr` and `Char` doesn't yield the same result when given an integer in the range `0..$FFFF`? I partly agree with both your reasons, but only partly (the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Chr) doesn't say you mustn't use `Chr` and in practice I don't think I have ever seen a difference).

Comment: For example, I've seen cases where `Chr(128)` may return `Char($20AC)` (`0x80` is the Euro symbol in some charsets).  Whereas `Char(128)` is always `Char($80)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That doesn't happen on my 10.3.2 in Windows, 32-bit. I imagine it could depend on the OS (legacy?) locale settings, but looking at the assembly, that appears not to be the case. (I vaguely recall a compiler directive related to this, though.)

Comment: it is possible that it has since been fixed, but it wasn't always like that, and I learned a long time ago to not trust `Chr()` when converting an integer to a character, when a simple type-cast will suffice.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I agree that `#128` is problematic unless `{$HIGHCHARUNICODE ON}`, but `Chr(128)` seems safe. Still, I really don't mind using `Char` instead, so I have changed it (even though I don't think it makes any difference whatsoever in this case).

Comment: Also, if `x` is a UTF-16 codeunit within 0..$FFFF, isn't it also a (BMP) codepoint?

Comment: No. because of surrogates in the `$D800..$DFFF` range, which are not valid codepoints.

Comment: I know of these, but I thought they can be called "codepoints" too (albeit useless in their own).

Comment: Obviously, you can have integers with values in that range and *say* they represent codepoints, but from the perspective of the Unicode standard, *codepoints* in that range are strictly forbidden. Sure, the range is technically part of the BMP, but it is reserved for UTF-16's exclusive use.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Okay.